pycharm debugger too slow on every "step over"
I am using pycharm to debug a django web app. When I click "step over" to direct debugger to the next line, around 50-100 background jobs launches in pycharm (as shown in the image which is taken from status bar of PyCharm) and it takes a few second(!) for the debugger to settle and show new values and be able to catch next "step over". This will impede development speed.
I tried the same project with same virtual environment but with VSCode debugger and it worked perfectly! So there is something wrong with pycharm.


I'm not very sure about the time it takes for the step-over debugger functionality, because I can't find it. However, I do know that PyCharm have various complex functionalities that are achieved at the costs of speed. Also, my experience with PyCharm tells me that its debugger is basically useless.

Thank you @LukeL I found that it's a bug in pycharm 2024: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42044  After downgrading to 2023 it fixed!

Your welcome. PyCharm is the ideal IDE in more ways than one, but always keep in mind its downsides as well. Speed is certainly one of them. The debugger is another one. So, it is completely normal for a debugger to run very slowly in PyCharm, because it is the combination of the two major shortcomings of PyCharm.
